# How to create an interactive .net demo application

Tags: .net, reflection, automation, interactive, demo

In an upcoming exhibition, I would like to have a splash screen with 5 buttons, each stating the key benefits of our .net application.

Once the user click on a button, I would like our .net application to open, navigate to an area and then potentially want a square box drawn on the application.

I have looked at 2 options :
a)UI automation fundamentals : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107.aspx
b).net Reflection -> InvokeMethod() option to call controls.

The first part is ok, that is the part to navigate to an area. Once there, how would one draw e.g. a boundary (dotted line) square box or for that matter any UI ontop of the .net application. Lets say I want to draw a red box around a graph control on our UI.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: WinForms, WebForms, WPF, Silverlight or even Console? Might be relevant to the answer.

Comment: My advice: Fake it with video.  It'll look nicer, respond faster, be more reliable, and be easier to produce.

Comment: @Joel, all true, but it wouldn't be interactive.

Comment: @Dour - sure it would, at least the part where you select which video to show.